# How to replace custom url old domain to new domain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to replace all url entire website with new domain and new permalink? I have 5k url to replace at my site.

Example :

- **Current URL:** `oldomain.com/2020/12/data-raid-4963.html`
  **Replace To**: `sub.newdomain.com/4963-2/`
- **Current URL:** `olddomain.com/2019/09/data-raid-2125.html`
  **Replace To:** `sub.newdomain.com/2125-2/`

Comment: Is that last `-2` fixed for all URLs? Do these two domains/hostnames point to different servers?

Comment: Yes fix for all URLs and two domain/hostname point is same servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the domains point to the same server, you would need to do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^20\d\d/\d\d/[a-z-]+-(\d+)\.html$ https://sub.newdomain.com/$1-2/ [R=301,L]
```

I've assumed the `data-raid` part of the URL-path can consist of any sequence of 1 or more of `a-z` (lowercase) or `-` (hyphen) characters only. If this is always literally `data-raid` (as per your examples) then replace `[a-z-]+` accordingly in the regex.

The `$1` backreference contains the digit sequence immediately before the `.html` at the end of the URL-path. In other words, the contents of the captured subpattern `(\d+)`.

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html